# Jquery plugin to collapse ul/li

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery plugin to expand/collapse ul,li something like a accordion menu
My fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/8CyrA/ although it runs fine in pc , it
doesn't recognize the plugin code in fiddle..my question is there are 2 folders
Folder 1 , Folder 2 .. i want Folder2 to be in a collapsed state how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rearranged some things and now it seems working: http://jsfiddle.net/G8XNp/

- all script to the script panel
- put the script to the head

Comment: thanks szajmon :) can u help me in getting the Folder2 in collapsed state .. is this complex to do ?

Comment: you mean it should be collapsed by default?

Comment: start with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/masnR/ it does the trick with the collapseArrow CSS class, but its far from perfect as it is now :)